# Whitelabel Error Page Problem accessing Swagger

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

When trying to access the Swagger documentation, I face this error:

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
> /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Wed Sep 23 09:38:17 BRT 2020 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
> Found, status=404). No message available

I don't know what can be...

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Class configuration:

```
package com.simulacao.api.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket bancoApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.simulacao.api"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/*.*"))
                .build()
                .apiInfo(metaInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo metaInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("API Rest")
                .description("\"API Rest\"")
                .version("1.0.0")
                .license("Apache License Version 2.0")
                .licenseUrl("https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0\"")
                .build();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/customer")
@Api(value = "API Rest Customer")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @GetMapping
    @ApiOperation(value = "Returns a list of customers")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Customer>> showAll() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(this.customerService.findAll());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add those configs

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {


    //Swagger UI property
    registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}
```

This must be declareted in the config of implementation with "WebMvcConfigurer".

More information here : https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/

Answer (score 0):

For Spring Boot with SpringFox 3 all you need is following:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

and `/swagger-ui.html` is now `/swagger-ui/index.html` or `/swagger-ui`. From [doc](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/)

> swagger-ui location has moved from http://host/context-path/swagger-ui.html to http://host/context-path/swagger-ui/index.html OR http://host/context-path/swagger-ui/ for short

Comment: I have the same problem but I couldn't open it. Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75391306/cannot-open-swagger-2-in-spring-boot-3-app